# Customizing a responsive drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to integrate [Responsive Nav](http://responsive-nav.com/) into my site, and experiencing some difficulty establishing the desired layout.

I've created a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/erM2U/); you can resize the width of the "results" panel to see the navigation bar collapse into the responsive drop down menu icon. The functionality of the actual drop down bar is perfect; however, the issue I'm having is in trying to make the nav links *float alongside the header* when it's not collapsed into the menu. Thus, instead of having the (uncollapsed) list of links fall beneath the header, I'd like them alongside it, but drop down beneath when the icon is activated by the script.

The CSS is a combination of my own, and some from an example by the developer of the plugin. I guess I'm ultimately looking at having the `nav#primary ul` float left against the header (H1), and then `display:block` when collapsed into the responsive navigation bar.

Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this → http://jsfiddle.net/matbloom/3DUj5/

This should do the trick:

```
nav#primary {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
```

Just adjust the width of #primary to work with your presentation and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks Matt-- with that solution though there still exists the problem of the menu links remaining floated to the right upon expansion of the responsive drop-down, whereas upon click I'd like the links to display exactly as they do in my initial example; not sure how to effect this..

Comment: Hi Matt-- thanks for your assistance here; your adjustments look perfect in Firefox, but I'm seeing that in Chrome the links, while now aligned right, are still dropping below the header; any ideas?

Comment: Hi @nickpish, you're right. Update the first 'header h1' with 'display: inline':

`header h1 {
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
}`